# Dynamic Links Custom Path not applied in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I have setup *Firebase Dynamic Links* with an URL in the following format: `a.b.c/d`

However, **emails** sent by *Firebase Authentication* contain Dynamic Links of the format `a.b.c/?link=...` instead of `a.b.c/d/?link=...`, which means that they do not work.

I followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth) / [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) to send the links.

Whenever I manually copy the link and add `d/` in the URL, the Dynamic Links will work since *Dynamic Links* is set up this way in Firebase Console and also in `firebase.json` for *Firebase Hosting*.

```
"appAssociation": "AUTO",
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/d/**",
    "dynamicLinks": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Firebase Auth does not support custom paths in dynamic links. This features was recently added to dynamic links and is not yet supported.

Comment: @bojeil So what should I do? The links simply do not work because of the wrong URL. And using just `a.b.c` would disable the underlying web site.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have a lot of choices. You will need to create a new custom domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, *Firebase Authentication* does not yet support custom paths in Dynamic Links as [*bojeil*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5081766/bojeil) pointed out (confirmed by Firebase support).
Unfortunately, [capturing URL segments in **Firebase Hosting** redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture_url_segments_for_redirects) does not support *query parameters*, which would be required to redirect `/?link=...` to `/d/?link=...`.

Because of these two unfortunate circumstances, I simply used some *JavaScript* to redirect any request to `/?link=...` to `/d/?link...`:

```
const link = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('link')
if (window.location.pathname == '/' && link != null && link != '') window.location = `a.b.c/d/${window.location.search}`
```